# Predicting a single image with Keras' ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm very new to deep learning so please forgive me for this probably simple question.

I trained a network to classify between `positive` and `negative`. To simplify the image generation and fitting process I used a `ImageDataGenerator` and the `fit_generator` function, as shown below:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Simplified model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(12, 12, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

# Image import, for 'validation_generator' equally
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    './training/',
    target_size=(12, 12),
    batch_size=128,
    class_mode='binary')

# Compiling
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
             optimizer='adam',
             metrics=['acc'])

# Fitting, for Tensorboard 'history = model.fit_gen...'
model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=8,
                    epochs=50,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data = validation_generator,
                    validation_steps=8,
                    callbacks=[tb]) # Standard Tensorboard
```

I want to use my model to predict a single image (imported as `numpy array`) as shown below:

```py
image = 'single imported image with shape (12, 12, 3)'
model.predict(image)
```

However, the only thing I get is an error message stating the `Matrix size-incompatible`. I have tried `model.predict_generator()` on my `validation_generator` which works, but that isn't a single image.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do a prediction on a single image, do the following:

```
image = np.random.rand(12, 12, 3) # single imported image with shape (12, 12, 3)
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0) # image shape is (1, 12, 12, 3)
model.predict(image)
```

In other words, your model still expects input shape of `(None, 12, 12, 3)`. So, before doing the prediction, expand the dimensions of the image to be a batch of a single image.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much :) I'll accept after 10 minutes.

Comment: No worries. Glad that I can help!

Comment: Great answer. This also helped me with my current project.!