# Tensorflow predict from image url?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reshape

I want to predict from image url. In the past, I use ImageDatagenerator().flow_from_directory() methods, but now I have only one image. so I want to predict from this single image.

I have tried the below code, but failed. (Dimension error)

```
url = "http://3.36.149.28/uploads/WEBUPLOADprofile.png"
img = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
img = img_to_array(img)
img = img/255.

#Predict
pred = model.predict(img)
```

so I tried reshape & retrying, but failed (cannot reshape array of size 1048576 into shape (28,28,1))

```
img = img.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
img = img/255.

#Predict
pred = model.predict(img)
```

for getting reshape & get colored predict image, what can I do ? please help..

Additional : I trained srcnn model, and inputs :

```
inputs = Input((None, None, 3), dtype='float')
```

Comment: What is the size of the train images? Alternatively, what does `model.summary()` says about the shape of input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem.

First, my url image shape is (None, None, 4), but my trained shape is (None, None, 3).

So I tried another jpg image (None, None, 3) and expand dimension via np,
and result shape = (1, None, None, 3)

```
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
model.predict(image)
```

from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57658609/12605128)

and now I get predict image successfully.